# Output always gives []

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, filter

I am trying to filter some data by "averageRating".

This is my code for the method:

```
filterr(request, respond) {
        var averageRating = request.params.rating;
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM shopreview.shops WHERE averageRating = ?";
        db.query(sql, [averageRating], function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            else {
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

My sql statement is working when I test it against my database. However, I keep getting [] as my result. Can someone please help identify what the problem is? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Never ever have SQL query in your JS!

Comment: filterr with double r?

Comment: The problem is probably because i cannot parse the "averageRating"  value into the '?'

Comment: @NoOorZ24 The user could be using JS on the backend and we don't know why they're working on this. It could just be a learning exercise. Let's not discourage them :)

What is the exact query as you run it against your database? Are you sure that your code is accessing your database correctly/the correct database?

Comment: Debug your code using `console.log` to see the value of `averageRating` maybe the variable is in the `body` or `query` of the request

Comment: I already checked it does display the "averageRating" that i have in my input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that "?" since the db is unable to parse it.

either add that avarageRating variable like so:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM shopreview.shops WHERE averageRating = ${parseInt(avarageRating)}";
```

or if you're using couchbase you could parse it like this:

```
var sql = `SELECT * FROM shopreview.shops WHERE averageRating = $1`;
```

where $1 is the first variable in the array of variables.

Comment: Thanks alot, I never thought of that.

Comment: I'm assuming rating is an integer in both DB and request. What I did was just added the integer to the sql string. You should remove that dependency array and just add your avarage rating in the sql string either by concatanating "rating = " + avarageRating or like me, using template literals :)

Comment: I have a similar error now but i not sure if it is due to datatype this time

Comment: debug debug debug, always have your queries as strings :) good luck

Comment: I'm taking a break at work right now, but I'd rather not dive into private messaging since I don't do tutoring of any kind. Sorry, man.